# Elasticsearch - Aggregating on multiple fields, filtering on count and ordering on count

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm a bit new to aggregations and I want to create an equivalent to the following SQL:

```
select fullname, natcode, count(1) from table where birthdate = '18-sep-1993' group by fullname, natcode having count(1) > 2 order by count(1) desc
```

So, if I have the following data:
[image]

I need to get the results as:
[image]

As you can see, the results are grouped by fullname and natcode, have count>2 and are ordered by count

I've managed to form the following query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "profs": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "birthDate": "18-Sep-1993"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "name_count": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "fullName.raw"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "nat_count": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "natCode"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "my_filter": {
                  "bucket_selector": {
                    "buckets_path": {
                      "the_doc_count": "_count"
                    },
                    "script": {
                      "source": "params.the_doc_count>2"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**What is achieved:**
It is filtering on date, creating bucket on fullname (name_count) and sub-bucket on natcode (nat_count) and filtering natcode bucket on doc count.

**The problem with this:**
I can see empty name_count buckets also. I only want buckets that have the required count. Following is the sample of results

```
"aggregations": {
    "profs": {
      "doc_count": 3754,
      "name_count": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 4,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 3732,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "JOHN SMITH",
            "doc_count": 3,
            "nat_count": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": [
                {
                  "key": "111",
                  "doc_count": 3
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "MIKE CAIN",
            "doc_count": 3,
            "nat_count": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": [
                {
                  "key": "205",
                  "doc_count": 3
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "JULIA ROBERTS",
            "doc_count": 2,
            "nat_count": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": []
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "JAMES STEPHEN COOK",
            "doc_count": 2,
            "nat_count": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": []
            }
          }
```

In the results, I don't want the last two names (JULIA ROBERTS and JAMES STEPHEN COOK) to show up

**Additionally what is missing:**
The ordering on the group count at the end. I'd want the group (fullname, natcode) with the most count to show up

**Required further ahead:**
The grouping needs to be done on a couple of more fields, so they'd be like 4 fields.

Please excuse if I might have used any wrong terms. Hopefully you get the idea of what help is required. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is how your query should be.

### Required Query *(Final Answer)*

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "birthDate": "18-sep-1993"
        }
      }
    }
  }, 
  "aggs": {
    "groupby_fullname": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "fullName.raw",
        "size": 2000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "natcode_filter": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "hits": "groupby_natcode._bucket_count"
            },
            "script": "params.hits > 0"
          }
        },
        "groupby_natcode": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "natCode",
            "size": 2000,
            "min_doc_count": 2
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Alternative Solution: (Similar to select distinct)

As last resort, what I can come up with is to do something like select distinct based on `fullName + "_" + natCode`. So basically your keys would be of form `JOHN SMITH_111`. This does give you accurate result except that the keys would be in this form.

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{  
   "size":0,
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "filter":{  
            "term":{  
               "birthDate":"18-sep-1993"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "aggs":{  
      "name_count":{  
         "terms":{  
            "script":{  
               "inline":"doc['fullName.raw'].value + params.param + doc['natCode'].value",
               "lang":"painless",
               "params":{  
                  "param":"_"
               }
            }
         },
         "aggs":{  
            "my_filter":{  
               "bucket_selector":{  
                  "buckets_path":{  
                     "doc_count":"_count"
                  },
                  "script":"params.doc_count > 2"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The query you have advised is not giving me what is expected. I've updated more details of sample data and the results that are required.

Comment: @Maarab I got the cases of the fieldname (typed fullname instead of full**N**ame wrong. Could you please test the query now and let me know if it works. Running the above query (both of them), on the data you've mentioned in the question, gives the result you are looking for.

Comment: fullname in the data sample is db column name.
I ran the queries and not getting any bucket in the results (Sorry don't know how to format)
Result 1:
`"aggregations": {
    "profs": {
      "doc_count": 53,
      "name_count": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 42,
        "buckets": []
      }
    }
  }`

Result 2:
`"aggregations": {
    "name_count": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 42,
      "buckets": []
    }
  }`

Comment: @Maarab Apologies. I've mistakenly used the "birthDate": "18-Sep-1933" instead of "birthDate": "18-Sep-1993" which I've corrected in the answers. Please try once again, the same queries and let me know if it works out. If it still doesn't could you please share me your mapping details.

Comment: hey @Maarab any luck so far? :|

Comment: Yes, I just ran it and it kinda seems to be giving me what I require but I need to test a bit more to conclude. Also your suggestion on the filter first is very right. The second query is how the query should be structured i.e. filter first and then apply aggregations. Will try to post the final update after testing.

Comment: Two observations:
1. 2 buckets are returned instead of 19 i.e. I can see two names with 3 doc_count each. There should be 17 more names and respective doc_counts > 2
2. One of the returned should have doc_count 4 instead of 3 (currently returned).

Comment: @Maraab, Could you share the dataset. I've tried few things at my end and everything looks good. You can configure number of buckets by adding `size` in the terms query to see more bucket count. for e.g. `"terms" : { "field":"fullName.raw", "size":20 }`

Comment: Ah I see why it might return doc_count 3 instead of 4, because the aggregation is applied to count `natCode` occurrences. You might have a document having `fullName` and `birthDate` that matches the query but that may not have `natCode`.

Comment: This is interesting. I added size to the name_count bucket as you suggested. When I put size = 20, it still showed 2 names. For size = 200, 7 names. For size = 2000, 20 names (should be 19). Another interesting observation is that the doc_count changed to 4 for size 2000 where it was showing 3 earlier (so it is not the nationality difference). Also there is 1 additional name showing that has count 2 for 1 nationality and 1 for another nationality, so in total it becomes more than 2 for that name. However what is required is that the count be per nationality in the condition > 2.

Comment: I will do some more research and get back to you. As for results are improving with bigger size number that is because term aggregation counts are approximate. This link should help. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-approximate-counts So its like, better to add bigger size to get more accurate result. :| Also please check the alternative solution I've updated. It does give you accurate result but format of keys are concatenation of fullName and natCode

Comment: @Maarab Could you please check the section `Required Query(Final Answer)`. I've got it working **finally**. Phew!! Must have spent decent quite time but happy to have found this. Please test and let me know if it solves your requirement. :)

Comment: @Maarab Did you get chance to test the query. Note that the doc count is maintained with `"min_doc_count": 2` in the query.  You can change it to `3` to test your use case. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Kamal, I tried the first query and it does work as expected so didn't go for the second one. Thank you. If you could please verify my understanding of how the query executes: Filters records having birth_date. Aggregates nationalities under name and returns buckets having min count = 2 and empty buckets. The bucket selector removes the empty buckets. Only the names with buckets are returned at the end. My confusions...
1. If we put min count, why do empty groupby_natcode buckets return?
2. What is size actually doing?
You can point me to resources if you like

Comment: @Maarab. The latest query I've provided should not give you empty buckets. The `min count` would return natCodes with count >= `2` if you put `2`. Size would actually return the total number of buckets. By default its `10`. When I mentioned `2000` it would return you `2000` buckets if you have that much data that qualifies the conditions as per the query.  For e.g. in `groupby_fullname` it would return 20 buckets if you mention `size` as `20`

Comment: Link as per your request https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html

Comment: The query you have provided does not return empty buckets and works fine. My question is, why do we have to put the bucket selector condition additionally if we have already specified min_doc_count? Also what I don't understand is that the total number of buckets/names returned are 19 (exactly as required) so why doesn't specifying size = 20 in groupby_name do the job and size = 2000 does?

Comment: Let's say for a bucket for e.g. `John`, you have 5 documents with  5 different natcodes, without the filtering condition, you would observe this key in the result in `groupby_fullNames` although its `groupby_natCodes` would show no result. Having that condition would filter parent bucket `John` in the first place. You can simply remove the filtering part and run the query to see how it'd work.

Comment: As for the `size`, you might want to read how Term Aggregation works. Read this link thoroughly https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-approximate-counts Last but not the least, if you think the answer helped, feel free to upvote and accept the answer. ;) More questions are always welcome.